# Fixed - Why can't I display some Civi contact fields through CivCRM Entity in Drupal 8?

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-8

I've got a development site running using Drupal 8.7.7/Civi 5.17.5 and CiviCRM Entity. I want to set up some Views to display Civi data. Some fields are being displayed fine (e.g. first name, last name), but other fields from the contact record appear to be empty, when I know, by looking at the CiviCRM contact records, that these fields are populated.

As an example, I want to display the Birth Date field. I have nearly 200 records where this field is populated.

If I look at the CiviCRM Entity display of the contact record (e.g. www.example.com/civicrm-contact/xxx (where xxx is the contact ID) I can see some of the fields in the contact record but not Birth Date, despite the fact that www.example.com/admin/structure/civicrm-entity/civicrm-contact/display indicates that this field is not disabled.

How can I get CiviCRM Entity, and Views to display this field correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graham - I've reproduced that. Not seeing the date of birth field either. Seeing lots of other dates though. Not sure what's going on. Could you please open an issue here: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/issues

**Update:** this is now top of the list for D8CE.

**Updated:** this is fixed now as of https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/pull/190

Comment: Right now this does indeed appear to be a bug, so I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: Hi Graham - wanted to ensure you know this is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the Drupal 8 setup but maybe be worth checking, have you got the Views integration prefixes in your setting file?

Should find them under: `/civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1`

Read more: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/

Comment: Not needed in Drupal8